# How to test Apache Nutch plugin via some use cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, plugins, nutch

I have wrote a simple plugin in java for Nutch 2.3.1 using some guide from this [site](http://grokbase.com/t/nutch/user/164c34pq8m/adding-a-new-field-to-nutch-mongodb-datastore-using-plugin). Now I have to test it so that I am sure that it is working properly before I integrate it to Nutch. If I simply run by java command then its give classes not found error. How can I test my plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you wrote an `IndexingFilter` plugin right? my usual recommendation is to take a look at a plugin somehow "similar" to the one you wrote, for instance let's take the `index-anchor` plugin and checkout how the tests of this plugin is written, take a look at https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/src/plugin/index-anchor/src/test/org/apache/nutch/indexer/anchor/TestAnchorIndexingFilter.java. If your plugin read some values from the configuration (a configuration option a path to a file, etc.) you should take a good look at the 36-39 lines (https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/2.x/src/plugin/index-anchor/src/test/org/apache/nutch/indexer/anchor/TestAnchorIndexingFilter.java#L36-L39).

The general idea es to instantiate the filter that you just wrote, feed it some fake data and assert on the result of the execution of the filter. Although the information on https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample-0.9 is specific to the 1.x branch of Nutch it contains general guidelines that could help you get there.

Some plugins also implement the `main()` method allowing to be invoked using the `bin/nutch` script directly from the terminal, this is helpful when you want the user to "play"/test the configurations values without the need to run a crawl. Once you implement the `main()` method you can invoke your plugin using the `bin/nutch plugin <plugin name> <plugin class> [some additional parameters]` command. Keep in mind that the plugin must be activated in the `conf/nutch-site.xml` file. Take a look at https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/a3e7420494304bc4de7ee1a0b25a5158108856f5/src/plugin/urlfilter-regex/src/java/org/apache/nutch/urlfilter/regex/RegexURLFilter.java, this plugin is implemented for the 1.x version of Nutch but it could help you see in more details what I've talked about.

With this you 1) test your implementation in an isolated environment and 2) provide a testing environment for the user/you if for instance your plugin have an additional configuration file with many different options. And my final recommendation: always execute the entire test suite of Nutch before deploying and run a small test crawl to make sure everything is ok.